# Linux fails on boot in strange way

Tags: boot, slackware

I have restarted my machine after trying to install Skype, i have reverted changes made to

```
etc/dbus-1/system.conf
```

but after starting my machine i receive almost instantly stream of 99 and sometimes 80 and that's all. Nothing is being logged to aby log as it fails even before loading kernel,literally in Second or two after pressing Power.

I don't know if my change to above file is relevant,maybe that's just coincidence, where I should start looking for some clue? I even don't know what to Google now, or is it software or hardware (ssd?) failure.

Comment: What do you mean by "I receive almost instantly stream of 99 and sometimes 80 and that's all. "? Are you talking about a progress indicator?

Comment: No,it's just corrupted output, I have probably broken somehow my bootsector, i'm trying to fix it now.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've resolved it. Fortunately, everything is fine, that was `only` issue with bootsector. Failure even before kernel load pointed me towards MBR, so I've started system with my pendrive kept for such occasions with portable win, linux and several tools, mounted my disks (first relief - filesystem was fine) simply `chroot`ed (please see edit below) to my regular root and called

```
lilo -v
```

and my system is alive again. I'm very curious what could made such strange error, I've already modified file mentioned in my question and of course it doesn't change anything, system starts with my changes and without them. I haven't touched anything connected with bootsector, or even anything in system's internals, so that's very disturbing, I'd really prefer if it was my failure.

Was that some error on my SSD? Or some cosmic rays? Or maybe virus? I don't know, if anyone has any idea how to reproduce that error I'll happily try it.

Edit: As @peterph wrote, "it is a Good Idea (TM) to bind-mount `/dev` and `/proc` into the appropriate places in your root partition before chrooting into it" - thanks for noticing that.

Comment: Might have been a spurious error (even a read error in BIOS) - I've seen such thing once or twice and I don't have any better explanation for it. For the posterity you might want to add to your answer that it is a Good Idea (TM) to bind-mount `/dev` and `/proc` into the appropriate places in your root partition before chrooting into it.